# Game algebraic Riccati equation

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control

Let $A$, $B_1$, $B_2$ and $C_1$ be known matrices of appropriate size,  $M$ is a positive definite solution of following equation. How can I solve the following discrete Riccati equation with Matlab?

$$M = A^T M \left(I + \left(B_2 B_2^T - \gamma^{-2} B_1 B_1^T \right) M \right)^{-1}A + C_1^T C_1$$

Thanks in advance!

PS: I refer to this [lecture](http://users.abo.fi/htoivone/courses/robust/hsem.pdf).

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry ,l forget to mention that  $M$ matrix is unknown , and other matrices all both known. besides, the gamma is a poitive real number. This equation is on page 35 of the lecutre.

Comment: You can solve it numerically by iterating  $$M_{k+1} = A^T M_{k} \left(I + \left(B_2 B_2^T - \gamma^{-2} B_1 B_1^T \right) M_{k} \right)^{-1}A + C_1^T C_1$$ with $M_0$ being set to be an arbitrary positive definite solution. The convergence guarantee for this Riccati equation is not sure. But you can refer to this book: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Numerical_Solution_of_Algebraic_Riccati/Gi1jZAz3pncC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The+Riccati+Equation+numerical&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this problem! Thank you for recommending this book, it is very useful to me!